# image rotate causing background change

Tags: php, image

i wrote code with flips image and then rotate it at -60 degree, issue is that rotated parts background is more darker than original image.

**used sample image is transparent png image**

summary of what i did
1: i make white layer A
2: put image on layer A using imagecopyresampled
3: flipped layer A , rotated Layer A

image used :http://img10.deviantart.net/07aa/i/2013/058/2/7/png_branch_by_moonglowlilly-d5wdjdp.png

output image
[output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FtRzY.jpg)

```
$image1=imagecreatefrompng($_GET["v1"]);
$image2=imagecreatefrompng($_GET["v1"]);
//filter_opacity( $image1, 25 );

$w=imagesx($image1);
$h=imagesy($image1);
$finala = imagecreatetruecolor($w, $h);
$finalb = imagecreatetruecolor($w, $h);
$finalc = imagecreatetruecolor($w, $h);

$backgroundColora = imagecolorallocate($finala, 255,255,255); // white bg
$backgroundColorb = imagecolorallocate($finalb, 255,255,255); // white bg
$backgroundColorc = imagecolorallocate($finalc, 255,255,255); // white bg

imagefill($finala, 0, 0, $backgroundColora);
imagefill($finalb, 0, 0, $backgroundColorb);
imagefill($finalc, 0, 0, $backgroundColorc);


$percent = 0.583;
$new_width = $w * $percent;
$new_height = $h * $percent;
$wshift = $w/8.5;
$hshift = $h/2.5;


imagecopyresampled($finala, $image2,$wshift,$hshift,0,0, $new_width, $new_height, $w, $h);
imagecopyresampled($finalc, $image2,$wshift,$hshift,0,0, $new_width, $new_height, $w, $h);
imagecopyresampled($finalb, $finalc,$w*0.3,$h*0.3,0,0, $w*0.6, $h*0.6, $w, $h);
imageflip($finala, IMG_FLIP_HORIZONTAL );


$finala = imagerotate($finala, -60, imageColorAllocateAlpha($finala, 255, 255, 255, 127));
imagecopyresampled($finalb, $finala,-$w*0.1,-$h*0.1,0,$h*0.20, $new_width, $new_height, $w, $h);
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
imagejpeg($finalb);
imagedestroy($finala);
imagedestroy($image2);
imagedestroy($image1);
imagedestroy($final);
```

Comment: Dunno if that is the problem, but why are you using an alpha value of 127 in imagerotate? Since you have no opacity, 255 would surely be more appropriate? And why do you comment 255^3 as "gray" instead of "white"?

Comment: Again, try  imageColorAllocateAlpha($finala, 255, 255, 255, 255) instead of  imageColorAllocateAlpha($finala, 255, 255, 255, 255). It might be that the area outside the rotated image has an opacity below one and then, when the images are merged, the part with a small opacity appears lighter than the rotated image. Also, is the white in the original image really pure white? Haven't checked yet. And, please, try to write out sentences. Edit: ah, your original image has indeed opacity. Uh, I need to check some things.

Comment: Addition: Your original image has full opacity for it's background color. Try to go with  imageColorAllocateAlpha($finala, 255, 255, 255, 0) to match that.

Comment: tried using imageColorAllocateAlpha($finala, 255, 255, 255, 0)  still same issue.

Comment: In the JPG you linked, there is no difference between the backgrounds - can you give us some output that has alpha-values? Best would be PNG I guess.

Comment: you want output as png instead of jpg , output is jpg

Comment: see one more sample : goo.gl/injzqq

Comment: My mistake, the colors are different. 255^3 becomes 253^3 for some reason. Might be an imprecision of multiplication. What you could try is to use imagecreatetruecolor on the image before any operation.

Comment: can you guide way to do it